# crystal report initialize on x64

Tags: crystal-reports, 64-bit

I have a program that works properly on x86. also it works on systems with visual studio without error even on x64. but on x64 systems without visual studio, occur error when call reports. message exception is :

```
The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.
Source:
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Stack Trace:
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass..ctor()
```

and message that contain this decription :

```
An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.
Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.
Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.
```

my program is based on:

- .net framework 4
- visual studio 2012
- crystal report 13.0.2

and install CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2 sometimes.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution

Go to your application project, right click, and select "Properties"

On the Build tab, find the Platform Target combo box. It probably says, "Any CPU".

Change this to x86 and your project will compile for 32 bit only, thus eliminating the issue.